# Magento Top Cart Ajax Issue

Tags: ajax, magento, prototypejs, cart

I have implemented an Ajax based button on the listing page that will add the product through Ajax. However i am having problems with the cart shown on the top. I want to update the cart as well.

The cart phtml file is located in `checkout/cart/topbar.phtml`
I am new to coding, since we need to give prototype.js http path to the file to process i can not find any http path to `topbar.phtml` so i can update the div with the content.
If anything is unclear please let me know.

I tried to be very specific about my problem.
I want to update the div containing top cart, the cart phtml is already there its being called from `$this->getChildHtml('topcart')` the file path in server is `checkout/cart/topbar.phtml`

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using one of these ready made extensions?

- [Ajax Cart LITE](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/j2tdesign/extension/4613/j2t_ajaxcart_lite)
- [Ajax Cart Pro](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aheadworks/extension/1185/ajax-cart-pro)
- [Ajax Cart Basket](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/webkul/extension/7013/ajax_cart_basket)
- [Ajax Cart Simple](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/BelVG/extension/5879/ajax_cart_simple)
- [Ajax Cart Professional](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/BelVG/extension/6125/ajax_cart_professional)
- [Ajax Cart Advanced](http://fisheye-webdesign.co.uk/shop/ajax-cart-advanced.html)
- [Ajax Add To Cart](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smivks/extension/3434/ajax-add-to-cart-extension)
- [Easy Ajax Product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magextend/extension/1944/easy-ajax-product)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i don't want to use any extensions. I already created some of the code using prototype to add a product into cart and it works fine.
The only place i am stuck is to update the top cart.
Its already being loaded i am just wondering how to reload it again after the product is added. (through prototype.js)

Answer (score 0):

In the admin section go to

```
System -> Configuration -> developer
```

after that go to the top left of the page and change the Current Configuration Scope to "Main website" and then change "*Template Path Hints*" and "*Add Block Names to Hints*" to *Yes*

Now, when you open the magento store you'll see the block names of every magento object, so look for the one you need and finally do:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('header_cart');
```